# Execute procedure with defined pl/sql table type in toad

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I have a package as such:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE someschema.somepackage
AS
    TYPE t_str_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (500)
                       INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    PROCEDURE some_procedure_p (in_first IN NUMBER, 
    in_second IN VARCHAR2, 
    in_third IN t_str_array, 
    in_fourth IN date, 
    in_fifth IN date,
    out_sixth_cur OUT t_some_ref);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY someschema.somepackage
AS   
   PROCEDURE some_procedure_p (in_first IN NUMBER, 
        in_second IN VARCHAR2, 
        in_third IN t_str_array, 
        in_fourth IN date, 
        in_fifth IN date,
        out_sixth_cur OUT t_some_ref);
        IS
        BEGIN
              FOR i IN in_third.FIRST .. in_third.LAST
              LOOP
                 ... do something
              END LOOP COMMIT;

              OPEN out_sixth_cur FOR
                 SELECT ... something;
        END;
END somepackage;
```

How do I execute this procedure in toad? So far I've tried:

Right click on the procedure, click execute package, call code is generated automatically:

```
DECLARE 
  IN_FIRST NUMBER;
  IN_SECOND VARCHAR2(32767);
  IN_THIRD someschema.somepackage.t_str_array;
  IN_FOURTH DATE;
  IN_FIFTH DATE;
  OUT_SIXTH_CUR someschema.somepackage.t_some_ref;

BEGIN 
  IN_FIRST := NULL;
  IN_SECOND:= NULL;
  IN_FOURTH := NULL;
  IN_FIFTH := NULL;
  OUT_SIXTH_CUR := NULL;

  someschema.somepackage.some_procedure_p ( IN_FIRST, IN_SECOND, IN_THIRD, IN_FOURTH, IN_FIFTH, OUT_SIXTH_CUR );

  :rc0_OUT_SIXTH_CUR := OUT_SIXTH_CUR;

  COMMIT; 
END;
```

I added:

```
  IN_THIRD := t_str_array('something');
```

But when I ran it like this, I got the following error:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'T_STR_ARRAY' must be declared
```

Why did I get this error if I already defined this type in the package spec?? I've tried many other ways as well but it always to complain about the type.

Comment: Why do you think you *don't* need to refer to it as someschema.somepackage.t_str_array for that assignment, as you do for the declaration a few lines before?

Comment: If you want to initialize the `in_third` local variable, you'd need to include the package name at a minimum.  You'd need to include the schema name as well if you're running as a different user.  `IN_THIRD := someschema.somepackage.t_str_array('something');` should initialize the `in_third` local variable.

Comment: I did, and I got the error: `PLS-00222: no function with name 'T_STR_ARRAY' exists in this scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the type name when you do the assignment (at least to package level; the schema is redundant if it's your package anyway but doesn't hurt here), as well as when you declare it in your anonymous block:

```
IN_THIRD := someschema.somepackage.t_str_array('something');
```

There is nothing at database/schema level called `t_str_array`, and if you don't qualify it Oracle doesn't know it needs to come from the package. You might think it's obvious; but there's nothing stopping you having the same type name defined in more than one package, so you have to be clear and consistent.

But as you pointed out you then get

```
PLS-00222: no function with name 'T_STR_ARRAY' exists in this scope
```

... because it's a table type, not a varray, so it's instantiated when its declared. You don't need to explicitly instantiate it, which is why Toad hasn't done that for you. [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS00501) shows this type of collection is initialised as 'empty' rather than null.

To populate it you just assign a value, using an index position:

```
IN_THIRD(1) := 'something';
```

So the whole block would become:

```
DECLARE 
  IN_FIRST NUMBER;
  IN_SECOND VARCHAR2(32767);
  IN_THIRD someschema.somepackage.t_str_array;
  IN_FOURTH DATE;
  IN_FIFTH DATE;
  OUT_SIXTH_CUR someschema.somepackage.t_some_ref;

BEGIN 
  IN_FIRST := NULL;
  IN_SECOND:= NULL;
  IN_THIRD(1) := 'something';
  IN_FOURTH := NULL;
  IN_FIFTH := NULL;
  OUT_SIXTH_CUR := NULL;

  someschema.somepackage.some_procedure_p ( IN_FIRST, IN_SECOND, IN_THIRD, IN_FOURTH, IN_FIFTH, OUT_SIXTH_CUR );

  :rc0_OUT_SIXTH_CUR := OUT_SIXTH_CUR;

  COMMIT; 
END;
```

I'd suggest you consider changing the name of your type though; giving a table type a name that suggests it's an array is (clearly!) confusing. They are known as both associative arrays and index-by tables, so you could argue it's fine as it is, but I kind of assumed it was a varray based both on the name and how you were trying to use it. (I should have checked, of course).

Comment: I tried fully qualifying it and also did a spell check, but I still got the PLS-00222 error.

Comment: @user3224907 - yes, missed it was a table type; updated the answer. You don't need to refer to t_str_array again.